# Translating Hex/Binary in C retrieved from COM Port

Tags: c, binary

This is a little bit of a tough question to explain but I'll give it a shot. I am retrieving some data from a COM port and expect to find binary values of:

```
01011100101010100011010101101101
```

which I believe corresponds to a decimal value of: 1554658669

Instead I am only able to retrieve the data bit by bit in the following hex values which correspond to the below binary:

```
5D AA 35 6D
01011100 10101010 00110101 01101101
```

I am new to binary/hex/C and realized quickly that 5DAA356D is not equivalent to 1554658669

Both sets of binary above are the same expect for the spaces. I want to know what steps to take to get that decimal value from those sets of hex codes in C.

Thanks

Comment: The first byte corresponds to 5C (instead of 5D)

Comment: yes that was a type, my bad. either way, the issue still stands.

Comment: Huh?  Sorry, but your question is not clear.

Comment: `unsigned char byte[4];` `/* bytes then filled somehow */` `unsigned long value = byte[0]*(1lu << 24) | byte[0]*(1lu << 16) | byte[0]*(1lu << 8) | byte[0]*(1lu << 0);`

Comment: @user3716857: 1554658669 (decimal) _is_ equal to 5CAA356D (hex). What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Any number from any base (2 [binary], 8 [octal], 16 [hexa]) can be converted to number in decimal base. Or in simple words for hexa to decimal conversion or binary to decimal conversion you can use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) from stdlib.h.